# menu items do not show on the actionbar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

i am tryin to show menu contents on the action bar "the horizontal black bar". i wrote the below code and the menu contains some items as shown in the 
xml file belwo, but the problem is at run time , all the items appears when the setting button pressed and none of them appears on the action bar!

I am using android studio with the build.gradle file posted below.

please let me know how to force the menu item to appear on the actionbar?

**code**:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onCreateOptionsMenu"));

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    if (!this.mScanning) {
        Log.d(TAG, SubTag.msg("onCreateOptionsMenu", "no scanning"));

        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_cancel).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null);

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, SubTag.msg("onCreateOptionsMenu", "scanning"));

        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_cancel).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**menu.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".actMain">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="refresh"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_scan"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/menu_scan"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_cancel"
    android:title="@string/menu_cancel"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_exit"
    android:title="@string/menu_exit"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

**gradle.build**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.com.bt_11"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
}
```

**style.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
     <style name="AppTheme"       
 parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: where you want to show this on action bar or on clicking overflow menu button on actionbar

Comment: @Pavan on action bar

Comment: you have to consider the space available also you are no using icon so you had to use showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" this and the other will go on overflow menu

Comment: @Pavan i will try what you suggested, but i am not using icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this piece of code, replace showAsAction="always" with showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"

```
 <menu 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:hmkcode="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".actMain" >

<item
   android:id="@+id/menu REFRESH"
   android:orderInCategory="1"
   android:title="refresh"
   hmkcode:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>

<item
   android:id="@+id/menu_scan"
   android:checkable="true"
   android:orderInCategory="2"
   android:title="@string/menu_scan"
   hmkcode:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>

<item
  android:id="@+id/menu_cancel"
  android:title="@string/menu_cancel"
  android:orderInCategory="100"
  hmkcode:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>


<item
  android:id="@+id/menu_exit"
  android:title="@string/menu_exit"
  android:orderInCategory="101"
  hmkcode:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Comment: have you tried removing the orderInCategory tag? i have used the same piece of code pasted above without the orderInCategory tag and worded perfectly...

Comment: I tried it without android:orderInCategory but i still have the same problem..would please have a look at the style.xml and build.gradle files posted above!! maybe they contain something wrong

Comment: your buid.grandle file seems to have nothing out of the ordinary...have you tried using another theme in your style.xml file?...anyway does your Activity where the action bar located extend AppCompatActivity?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show only on click of overflow menu add this line

```
app:showAsAction="never"
```

if you want to show only if room then use this

```
app:showAsAction="always|ifRoom"
```

hope it will help you